# Insert UIView into UIToolbar

Tags: swift, uiview, uitoolbar

I'd like to insert an UIView into an UIToolbar. (see Picture)
I've already tried .addSubview but it doesn't work.
Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
 // Toolbar -> Done Butotn
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action:#selector(doneButtonClicked))

    toolbar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)

    self.TextInput.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the view as a `UIBarButtonItem` created from your custom view:

```
let someCustomView = ... // your custom view
let customItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: someCustomView)
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action:#selector(doneButtonClicked))

toolbar.setItems([customItem, flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)
```

And you should call `toolbar.sizeToFit()` after setting its items.